# Missing values time series plot

Tags: r, visualization, missing-data

I am using R and I have a list with several data frames containing meteorological data and I want to compare them using a bar plot to visualize missing data gaps, for example missing temp values between 2002 - 2005.

*All the data is on a daily basis.

[image]

Something like this:

Comment: Including a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) in your question will increase your chances of getting an answer.

Comment: just a point plot can work in this setting sometimes `ggplot(data, aes(date, siteid)) + geom_point()`

Answer (score 1):

The **imputeTS** R package has some missing data plots.

You could for example use:

```
library(imputeTS)
ggplot_na_distribution(station1)
```

As you can see in this example, only univariate time series are supported.
You would have to create a separate plot for each of your stations.